# How to add new struts portlet action hook in liferay 7?

Tags: liferay-7

How to register new struts-action path in liferay 7 ? and how to call that strutsportletAction class from jsp in liferay 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is a sample how you can do it

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/a2ed923d21338d30fbdbcba9e703f35edb8ae4d4/gradle/extensions/struts-action

But the question why you want to do it? There are way better way in Liferay 7 to expose endpoints. Have a look at the REST provider

https://dev.liferay.com/ca/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/jax-ws-and-jax-rs